# How can I import a JSON file into MySQL database, using a simple query, without actually converting it to any other file formats like CSV etc.?

Tags: mysql, json

I tried to import a JSON file which looks like:

```
[ 
{ 
"executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
"A":1,
"B":1
},
{ 
"executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
"A":2,
"B":2
},
{ 
"executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
"A":3,
"B":3
},
{ 
"executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
"A":4,
"B":4
}]
```

I want to import the above file into a mySQL DB, and i want my table to look somewhat like this:

```
 executionDateTime           A               B

2017-07-07 15:21:15          1               1
2017-07-07 15:21:15          2               2
2017-07-07 15:21:15          3               3
2017-07-07 15:21:15          4               4
```

I have tried the below query to do so (which would work out for me if the file format is CSV), but it didn't work.

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE '<path>/my_file.json' 
INTO TABLE database_name.my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

The above query gave me a table which looked like this:

[image: output_table]

(I KNOW, mySQL HAS AN INBUILT FUNCTION TO IMPORT A FILE, BUT I DO NOT WANT TO USE THAT FUNCTION, A QUERY IS WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR... :) )

Please suggest, if anyone had to face such a problem and got a solution. Please don't mark this question as a duplicate without giving a SOLUTION THAT ACTUALLY WORKS.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that in the near future there is a native functionality from MySQL.

An option (not simple query) is something like the following script (adapt as needed). Depending on the number of items may have performance problems.

File: `/path/to/file/loadsetProfile.json`:

```json
[
  {
    "executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
    "A":1,
    "B":1
  },
  {
    "executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
    "A":2,
    "B":2
  },
  {
    "executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
    "A":3,
    "B":3
  },
  {
    "executionDateTime":"2017-07-07 15:21:15",
    "A":4,
    "B":4
  }
]
```

**MySQL Command-Line**:

```mysql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `import_from_json`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `uuid_to_bin`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp_my_table`, `my_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp_my_table` (
    ->   `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `content` JSON NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
    ->   `executionDateTime` TIMESTAMP,
    ->   `A` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
    ->   `B` BIGINT UNSIGNED
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `uuid_to_bin` (`id` VARCHAR(36))
    -> RETURNS BINARY(16)
    -> DETERMINISTIC
    ->   RETURN UNHEX(REPLACE(`id`, '-', ''));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `import_from_json`(`_id` VARCHAR(36))
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `_id_current_json` BINARY(16) DEFAULT `uuid_to_bin`(`_id`);
    ->   DECLARE `_items_length`,
    ->           `_current_item` BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    ->   DECLARE `_content` JSON DEFAULT (SELECT `content`
    ->                                    FROM `temp_my_table`
    ->                                    WHERE `id` = `_id_current_json`);
    -> 
    ->   IF JSON_VALID(`_content`) THEN
    ->     SET `_items_length` := JSON_LENGTH(`_content`),
    ->         @`insert_import_from_json` := NULL;
    ->     WHILE `_current_item` < `_items_length` DO
    ->       SET @`insert_import_from_json` := CONCAT('
    '>         INSERT INTO `my_table` (
    '>            `executionDateTime`,
    '>            `A`,
    '>            `B`
    '>         )
    '>         SELECT
    '>           `content` ->> \'$[', `_current_item`, '].executionDateTime\',
    '>           `content` ->> \'$[', `_current_item`, '].A\',
    '>           `content` ->> \'$[', `_current_item`, '].B\'
    '>         FROM `temp_my_table`
    '>         WHERE `id` = \'', `_id_current_json`, '\'
    '>       ');
    ->       PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`insert_import_from_json`;
    ->       EXECUTE `stmt`;
    ->       SET `_current_item` := `_current_item` + 1;
    ->     END WHILE;
    ->
    ->     IF `_current_item` > 0 THEN
    ->       SET @`insert_import_from_json` := NULL;
    ->       DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    ->     END IF;
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> SET @`UUID` := UUID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/loadsetProfile.json' 
    -> INTO TABLE `temp_my_table`
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
    -> (`content`)
    -> SET `id` = `uuid_to_bin`(@`UUID`);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CALL `import_from_json`(@`UUID`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    ->   `executionDateTime`,
    ->   `A`,
    ->   `B`
    -> FROM
    ->   `my_table`;
+---------------------+------+------+
| executionDateTime   | A    | B    |
+---------------------+------+------+
| 2017-07-07 15:21:15 |    1 |    1 |
| 2017-07-07 15:21:15 |    2 |    2 |
| 2017-07-07 15:21:15 |    3 |    3 |
| 2017-07-07 15:21:15 |    4 |    4 |
+---------------------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and understanding the problem. I actually need to create a stored procedure, that has to be used by an automated process which will in turn fetch these files on a regular basis and will create new tables with the same table structure. Thanks again.

Comment: Tried the suggested query throws error. Also,  `SELECT VERSION();` gives **5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1**.

Comment: Query: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `temp_my_table`  (`id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,`content` JSON NOT NULL);`   Gives:     _Error Code: 1064_       **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL)' at line 1**

Comment: As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type. In previous versions there is no support for the JSON data type. See [11.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Answer (score 4):

Reference:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

I know this is an older thread, but MySQL 5.7 now has a JSON type where you can import JSON into a field, then you can use calculated fields to split the json into separate fields. Here's rough code (not tested):

Create a JSON Test Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jsontest(
     rowid INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     jsondata json,
     `executionDateTime` TIMESTAMP,
     `A` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
     `B` BIGINT UNSIGNED,
     );
```

Import your JSON into JSON field:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/testfile.json' into table jsontest(jsondata);
```

Split your Data Up (this could be combined into a single command)

```
UPDATE jsontest set executionDateTime=(jsondata->>'$.executionDateTime');
UPDATE jsontest set A=(jsondata->>'$.A');
UPDATE jsontest set B=(jsondata->>'$.B');
```

If you don't want to have extra fields, you can query the jsondata field like this:

```
SELECT jsondata->>"$.executionDateTime" AS executionDateTime,
       jsondata->>"$.A" AS A,
       jsondata->>"$.B" AS B;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this web page which transform json file in sql file, after that, I execute script in toad mysql and works.

URI of web I am using is [converter web](https://sqlify.io/conversion/30dfccd2-1e88-48f9-8f95-d2b05e16a9ad)

Comment: Your suggested tool doesn't work, I think the domain was expired. In case someone wants to convert from JSON to SQL query, you can use https://wtools.io/convert-json-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 0):

There is a native way in the GUI where you can import /export CSV and JSON files.
Step1. Launch WorkBench
Step2. Navigate to SQL Schema
Step3. Select Table
Step4. Once you select the table look for an icon marked result grid which shows up while hovering on the table(shows columns in the table and look for a small import icon right next to the edit option) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neFfY.png)
5. make sure to select the correct column for values and voila works 75% of the time the other 25% I just copy and paste the whole file into Postman.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).