# Insert raw file to mysql

Tags: mysql, json

I want to move a file consisting of raw file to MYSQL.

I want to assign the key in the raw file to the field and move the value to the data in the field, but I do not know what to do.

Is there a way to do it without directly inserting it?

**trying insert a raw file into MySQL.**

Help!

**Example raw files**

```
file1

[{"app":"unknown", "uid": "1000", "says": "hello"}, {"app":"hi", "uid": "1020", "says": "good"}]

file2

[{"app":"wowo", "uid": "20", "says": "asdf"}, {"app":"no", "uid": "1030", "says": "goso"}]
```

**Want MYSQL Result**

```
+-----------------+------+-------------+
| app             | uid  | says        |
+-----------------+------+-------------+
| unknown         | 1000 | hello       |
| hi              | 1020 | good        |
| wowo            |  20  | asdf        |
| no              | 1030 | goso        |
+-----------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: there are lots of ways - with workbench, with a programming language, or as [described at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075289/how-can-i-import-a-json-file-into-mysql-database-using-a-simple-query-without). what would you like to do?

Comment: @marmeladze I saw that article but I can not understand.

Comment: @marmeladze Can any programming language, workbench, etc., but I wonder if it works with mysql query

Comment: @SeonggwonYoon Just want to know if you are using some language like php to insert it , or you are trying insert a raw file into MySQL

Comment: @Sahil I'm trying insert a raw file into MySQL.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON array" or "JSON object". [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure. In order to be modified, the JSON has to be decoded into a data structure equivalent to that used to create the JSON. That data structure is an array or an object but it is not JSON and not related to the JSON concept in any way.

Comment: @axiac Thank you for letting me know. I thought it was a JSON array so far.

Comment: No, there's no such thing as a JSON array. JSON is just text. When you deserialise it using a programming language, it can be placed into a data structure such as an array etc. Anyway you can import JSON using Workbench, potentially. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html